# How can one derive the original data from the correlation- or covariance matrix of that data?

Tags: pca, data-transformation, dataset, covariance-matrix, correlation-matrix

How can one derive the original data from the correlation- or covariance matrix of that data?

I know the way a new, reduced dataset can be calculated from the correlationmatrix and it’s eigenvectors and eigenvalues in the PCA algorithm. But that is meant to give you a reduced dataset.

My purpose is to get the original dataset back from the correlationmatrix or covariancematrix only!

Comment: As a trivial but indicative example consider that a correlation of 1 is consistent with any sets of values $y = a + bx$ for which $b > 0$. Even knowing $a$ and $b$ too wouldn't restore the original $y$ and $x$ values.

Comment: Given that the covariance matrix has the form $$\operatorname{cov}(\mathbf{X},\mathbf{Y})
=\operatorname{K}_{\mathbf{X}\mathbf{Y}}=
\operatorname{E}
\left[
 (\mathbf{X} - \operatorname{E}[\mathbf{X}])
 (\mathbf{Y} - \operatorname{E}[\mathbf{Y}])^{\rm T}
\right]$$ It is not possible to reconstruct the original data without knowing the mean values of **X** and **Y**. Same thing for the correlation matrix which is calculated from the covariance matrix.

Answer (score 3):

**You can't.**

There are many different datasets which look exactly the same from a summary statistic point of view. Given only the correlation or covariance between features, it is not possible to determine what the original data was, since there are an infinite number of candidate datasets which would give you the same result. As a very simple example, any linear scaling of a data matrix changes the data values, but not the correlations among them, so there is no unique mapping from correlations back to data values.

See https://www.autodeskresearch.com/publications/samestats for examples of very distinct datasets that have near-identical summary statistics.